# Unable to resolve service for type 'SignalR.XXXX' while attempting to activate 'YYYYAPIController'

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

I have two services.

```
        services.AddControllers();
```

and

```
        services.AddSignalR()
           .AddHubOptions<OutputMessages>(options =>
           {
               options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
           });
        services.AddScoped<IOutputMessages, OutputMessages>();
```

second services is also confured:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
             endpoints.MapHub<OutputMessages>("/OutputMessages", options =>
            {
                options.Transports =
                HttpTransportType.WebSockets |
                HttpTransportType.LongPolling;
            });
```

I have interface for my SignalR service:

```
public interface ISignalRHandler 
{
    public void RestartProcessor(Guid containerId, string userId, string message);
    ....
}
```

and I inherits this interface and SignalR interface in my SignalR service realization

```
public class OutputMessages : Hub, IOutputMessages
{
    public OutputMessages(IHubContext<OutputHub> hubContext, ILogger<OutputMessages> logger, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
        _db = dbContext;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void SendUserMessage(string discordId, Guid containerId, string message)
    ....
}
```

I try to inject my SignalR service to controller service:

```
public class ApplicationAPIController : ControllerBase
{
    public ApplicationAPIController(ILogger<ApplicationAPIController> logger, ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IConfiguration Configuration, CoreObjectDumper.CoreObjectDumper dump, OutputMessages _outputMessages)
    {
```

But receive error message

*Unable to resolve service for type 'SignalR.OutputMessages' while attempting to activate 'ApplicationAPIController'.*

How is possible to solver this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add the OutputMessages as transient because you already doing that when you map your hub and add/use signalr.

```cs
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<OutputMessages>("/OutputMessages");
});
```

Then when you injecting to controller, it is recommended to inject the HubContext, and not the hub itself.

Example:

```cs
private IHubContext<NotificationsHub, INotificationsHub> NotificationsHub
{
    get
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<NotificationsHub, INotificationsHub>>();
    }
}
```

or in your case:

```cs
public ApplicationAPIController(ILogger<ApplicationAPIController> logger, ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IConfiguration Configuration, CoreObjectDumper.CoreObjectDumper dump, IHubContext<OutputMessages, IOutputMessages> _outputMessages)
```

> You generally shouldn't resolve the Hub out of DI. If you need to share code between your Hub and some other component, I'd suggest using either IHubContext or putting the shared code in a separate DI service instead.

Comment: If I inject instanciate class to controller IHubContext<OutputMessages, IOutputMessages> in run time I receive - Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub`1[IOutputMessages]' while attempting to activate 'OutputMessages'.

Comment: Same as your other question. Resolve the hub on DI and remove the constructor.